# WEKA Unable to determine structure as arff

Tags: java, scripting, weka

I am writing a script to do some classification using weka and I get an error when I try to run the classifier. I have converted the file from CSV using weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.

I have then removed some of the attributes from it using weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove -R 1,7,8

Now when I try to run the classifier on it using the command

```
java -classpath /home/jim/Downloads/weka-3-6-3/weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -p 0 -split-percentage 66 -preserve-order -t arff_input/Config38-R.arff
```

I get an error saying

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to determine structure as arff (Reason: java.io.IOException: premature end of file, read Token[EOF], line 1).
```

EDIT - I presume this is an error in my first line so here it is.

```
@relation 'Config38-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R1,7,8'
```

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem? Or have I made a mistake some where.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the first line to

```
@relation Config38
```

and now it works. No idea why this works and the above didn't I'm afriad

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the first line in .arff file it will also work.